# Convert Microsoft DOS code page OEM 737 to utf-8 in Rust

Tags: rust, utf-8

Thank you all in advance.
I have the below function and it works fine with text files created in my win10 pc but the program panics when the text is not utf-8. Our COBOL legacy application create OEM 737 (Greek charset). My question is how to convert OEM-737 to utf-8 in my Rust application

```
fn get_lines(file: &str) -> Vec<String>{
    
    let mut lines: Vec<String>= Vec::new();

    let file = File::open(file).expect("Error reading file");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    for line in reader.lines() {
        lines.push(line.unwrap().clone());
    }
    lines
}
```

Comment: Use a crate for that: https://crates.io/crates/oem_cp